# how to replace the tile template in the wp8 wmappmanifest with the one i have done manually through code?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8

I have done a small game and tried to create live tiles through code (eg:flip template) . The tile works perfectly .The problem is the tile i create is not replacing the default one in the wmappmanifest .

When i run the game the tile which i wanted is created and works fine , now when i long press the app/game i can still see the option "pin to startscreen" and when selected it creates the default tile created from the WMappManifest.

Now in the startscreen i can see 2 tiles . The one i created through code and the default one.

Is there anyway i can replace the default tile with the one i create through code?

Answer (score 1):

The default tiles can't be programmatically changed. 
This [MSDN Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202948%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)
can be helpful for your problem.

Thanks